# What are some IDS/IPS that are able to detect stealth scans done in nmap today?

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I was informed that these scans are no longer "stealth"

Comment: Welcome to Security SE. The answers to these kind of questions tend to get out of touch pretty soon. I recommend relying on your search for this

Comment: possible duplicate? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/what-scanning-tools-are-unlikely-to-set-off-network-ids

Comment: and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/frequency-of-stealth-scan

Answer (score 1):

Have seen Suricata, McAfee, PAN, and TippingPoint alert and even-potentially block on things like Nmap scans, but not if Sniffjoke or similar advanced evasion technique is utilized.

There are plenty of threads, even in this forum, about modifying Nmap to get through modern IDS/IPS without being noticed. Or just use like pbscan or write your own in Python or whatever else. Metasploit-framework even does things differently. It’s mostly about Window size, pps, retries, etc.